# Youtube API V3 commentThreads.list method not returning "shared privately" comments

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

While requesting the list of comment threads for a Youtube video there are certain comments that do not appear on the results:

1. Comments inside **private videos**
2. Comments that were **shared privately**

I understand this could be a normal response when using a **public API Key**. But this is happening even if I'm using **OAuth 2.0 with an access token** belonging to the user and channel owner of the target video.

It's there any workaround for this?

Many thanks in advance for anyone that can shed some light on the matter

Comment: Do this: upload a private video and public video to your channel as the owner. On the private video, submit some comments that are shared publicly and privately. On the public video, submit some comments that are only shared privately. Then, use the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#try-it) and authenticate your account to list the CommentThreads for each video and see if you can get the comments. If you can't, it might be a bug, which you can file [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Hi!, 
many thanks for the reply,
I forgot to mention that I did all kind of tests using the API explorer, so I can rule out any bugs from my side. So I guess I will file the bug and see what they say.
Thanks again